# проверка Email в чистом javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Валидация работает только если без проверки Email, то есть только проверка пустой строки, не могу понять почему не получается добавить проверку Email. Кто знает, подскажите плиз...

```js
function validateModal() {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;

  if (document.myForm2.Email2.value == "" || !re.test.document.myForm2.Email2.value) {


    document.myForm2.Email2.focus();
    var elementsEmail2 = document.getElementsByName("Email2")[0];
    elementsEmail2.className += " input_error";
    elementsEmail2.nextElementSibling.className += " active_error";

    return false;
  } else {
    var elementsEmailOk2 = document.getElementsByName("Email2")[0];
    elementsEmailOk2.classList.remove("input_error");
    elementsEmailOk2.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active_error");
  }
  return (true);
}
```

```html
<form action="#" name="myForm2" onsubmit="return(validateModal());">
  <input class="contact-block__input" type="text" name="Email2" placeholder="Email">
  <input class="contact-block__submit sent-order-btn" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что **`return true;`** а не **`return (true);`**

```js
function validateModal() {
  console.clear();
  console.log("start validation");

  var re = /^(([^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+(.[^<>()[]\.,;:s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z-0-9]+.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/igm;

  if (document.myForm2.Email2.value == "" || !re.test.document.myForm2.Email2.value) {

    console.log("not valid");

    document.myForm2.Email2.focus();
    var elementsEmail2 = document.getElementsByName("Email2")[0];
    elementsEmail2.className += " input_error";
    elementsEmail2.nextElementSibling.className += " active_error";

    return false;
  } else {
    var elementsEmailOk2 = document.getElementsByName("Email2")[0];
    elementsEmailOk2.classList.remove("input_error");
    elementsEmailOk2.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("active_error");
  }
  console.log("valid");
  return true;

}
```

```html
<form action="#" name="myForm2" onsubmit="return(validateModal());">
  <input class="contact-block__input" type="text" name="Email2" placeholder="Email">
  <input class="contact-block__submit sent-order-btn" type="submit" value="Отправить">
</form>
```